# Changing the x-axis labels of a ggplot histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have the following dataset (edited for readability):

```
chol <- read.table(url("http://assets.datacamp.com/blog_assets/chol.txt"), header = TRUE)
```

And I am creating a histogram of the data doing:

```
ggplot(data=chol, aes(chol$AGE)) + geom_histogram()
```

For a particular example I would like to change the x-labels however.

Any thoughts on how I can pull this of?

Comment: It might be helpful to have another hint on what is to be changed. I think you only want to apply a mapping from the (in this case with `bins = 30`) resulting 20, 30, 40, 50 and 60. But it would be better to know ;-)

Comment: use `aes(AGE)` rather than `aes(chol$AGE)`. Use `labs(x = "whatever")` to set the x-axis label

Comment: My understanding was to not change the x-axis title but the labels on the tics of the x axis ... what is the right understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To illustrate the answer (and better understand the question) a picture:

```
> require(ggplot2)
> chol <- read.table(url("http://assets.datacamp.com/blog_assets/chol.txt"), header = TRUE)
> ggplot(data=chol, aes(chol$AGE)) + geom_histogram()
```

yields:

[image: The plot]

There is the documentation (as we have a continuous not a discrete axis) at http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_continuous.html

For a discrete axis one might have simply written:

```
> p <- ggplot(data=chol, aes(chol$AGE)) + geom_histogram() + scale_x_discrete(labels=c("20" = "twe", "30" = "thi", "40" = "fou", "50" = "fif", "60" = "six"))  # does NOT work cf. surrounding text.
```

A continuous axis at least allows formatting (cf. link for details).

Comment: this is not really the solution to the question. There has to be some kind of a workaround... pls improve answer.